# Reading binary file with Octave

Tags: c, octave

I'm trying to a binary file consisting of floats with Octave (on OS X), but I'm getting the following error:

```
octave-3.2.3:2> load Input.dat R -binary
error: load: failed to read matrix from file `Input.dat'
```

The file was written like so:

```
std::ofstream fout("Input.dat", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Buf), N*sizeof(double));
fout.close();
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load Input.dat R -binary` expects the file Input.dat to be in Octave's binary file format.

You need to figure out what Octave's binary format is if you want to do it like that. However, if instead you want to output the file from C++ as you have, then you can read it in using Octave's [fopen](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html#doc-fopen) and [fread](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Binary-I_002fO.html) functions.

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look around for Octaves file format, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Try the code here (there's a big comment near the top of the file that gives the spec): http://www.google.com/codesearch#Y11mkMpBc8Y/pub/octave/bleeding-edge/octave-2.9.9.tar.gz%7CK3-pa5KXpC4/octave-2.9.9/src/ls-oct-binary.cc&exact_package=ftp://ftp.octave.org/pub/octave/bleeding-edge/octave-2.9.9.tar.gz&q=save_binary_data&type=cs